# How to include all fields in a multiple join into Linq statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

```
var largeset =
from invs in context.Invoices
join lines in context.InvoiceLines on invs.InvoiceId equals lines.InvoiceId
join tracks in context.Tracks on lines.TrackId equals tracks.TrackId into grp
select new
          {
              Invoice = invs,
              Detail = grp
          };
```

In the above join into statement, Detail is a list but it only contains Invoice and Track columns. I want to be able to get columns from InvoiceLine as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, then include inside the `select` whatever you like from the `lines` variable (which represents a single `InvoiceLine`, so you'd better call it `line`).

Comment: @Ivan, are you sure that will work? Each invoice has multiple lines. What I want is `{ Invoice, IEnumerable<InvoiceLine> }`

Comment: It wasn't clear that you want this. No, it will not work. How you will get the tracks then? Also, since this seems to be EF, don't you have navigation properties?

Comment: @Ivan, I was hoping `grp` will be a dataset that contains both `InvoiceLine` and `Track` but looks like that's not possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the line info list for the invoice, you need to move the `into` to the first `join` and perform the other `join` inside the outer `select`.

Something like this:

```
var largeset =
    from inv in context.Invoices
    join line in context.InvoiceLines on inv.InvoiceId equals line.InvoiceId into lines
    select new
    {
        Invoice = inv,
        Lines =
            from line in lines
            join track in context.Tracks on line.TrackId equals track.TrackId
            select new { Line = line, Track = track }
    };
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, wouldn't a join with groupby-into be better performance-wise? Your approach works but it is using a sub-select which is essentially executing a select to `Line` and `Track` for each `Invoice` record. Just look at the underlying SQL generated by your linq statement. See my answer as an alternative. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I can't say what is better because I don't have your model and also the query in your answer has totally different output from the one in the question. In general a query w/o group by is better than a query with group by when just selecting information :) But your does aggregates. Anyway, it's good to put what are you trying to achieve in the question. because now we are answering 2 totally different questions :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Ivan's solution which should yield better performance.

```
var largeset =
  from invs in context.Invoices
  join lines in context.InvoiceLines on invs.InvoiceId equals lines.InvoiceId
  join tracks in context.Tracks on lines.TrackId equals tracks.TrackId
  group new { invs, lines, tracks }
  by new
  {
      invs.InvoiceId,
      invs.InvoiceDate,
      invs.CustomerId,
      invs.Customer.LastName,
      invs.Customer.FirstName
  } into grp
  select new
  {
      InvoiceId = grp.Key.InvoiceId,
      InvoiceDate = grp.Key.InvoiceDate,
      CustomerId = grp.Key.CustomerId,
      CustomerLastName = grp.Key.LastName,
      CustomerFirstName = grp.Key.FirstName,
      CustomerFullName = grp.Key.LastName + ", " + grp.Key.FirstName,
      TotalQty = grp.Sum(l => l.lines.Quantity),
      TotalPrice = grp.Sum(l => l.lines.UnitPrice),
      Tracks = grp.Select(t => t.tracks)
  };
```